# what does SVN do when merging added files

Tags: svn

Say I add a big binary file into SVN in one branch (i.e. a new file) and then merge that revision into another branch.

When I commit my second branch, does a second copy of the file get sent to the server, or does SVN somehow recognise that file as a copy of the original as if I had done an svn cp?

Comment: By "merge that revision", you mean with svn merge?

Comment: yes. I presume all the different svn merges would work in the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you did the merge using standard Subversion tools, yes, the copy of the file on the branch will be identified as a continuation of the history of what is already on the server.

You can test this yourself, by looking at the output of `svn log -r0:HEAD --stop-on-copy --limit 1 -v /path/to/yourfile` and seeing that a copy source is present for the file.